# Port based routing in Istio with GRPC service on GKE Not Working

Tags: grpc, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

We are running GRPC services on Google Kubernetes Engine with Istio. We have done following setup for the request routing which is not working.

We are receiving following error while making GRPC call to service :
**upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers**

Please let me know if there is missing something or there is workaround.

```html
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: helloworld-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 50051
      name: grpc
      protocol: GRPC
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: helloworld
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - helloworld-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - port: 50051
    route:
    - destination:
        host: helloworld
        port:
          number: 50051
```

Comment: Is your HelloWorld application running with the istio-proxy sidecar? That means did you run `istioctl kube-inject` when deploying the application or is the namespace labelled with istio-injection=enabled?
Also, do you know if global mTLS is enabled? It can just be that the Gateway is trying to establish a mTLS connection while the helloworld application is only expecting unsecured connections.

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for reply. Here are my comments :

1. Yes we have default namespace enabled for istio-injection=enabled ( so sidecar gets there automatically )
2. Yes, we have Global mTLS enabled

I am still looking for solution. Please help.

Comment: Probably DestinationRule is missing. Have you tried to configure DR?
https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/destination-rule/